# Should i keep /var partition on my SSD?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd

I have bought Samsung 830 SSD (256GB capacity). I have moved my Win7 system partition (128 GB) to the SSD, and now i want to install Arch linux on the remaining 128GB. I just don't know how to organize my Linux partitions?
I like JFS but after reading some blogs i started thinking that EXT4 is better for the SSD. Also, i have no idea if i should keep my /var partition on the SSD. Some people say it's not good because of many write operations, some people say that /var on the SSD is not a problem since modern SSDs wear-down much slower.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put it anyway. According to Arch documentation, new SSD-s with good controllers (and Samsung is known for good controllers) won't be troubled as much as old / cheap SSD-s. Also, "var" partition can greatly influence system performance.
Now, from GRUB to fully loaded (and customized) XFCE it takes about 5 seconds. It's great result taking into account that i have old motherboard (with only SATA 2 controllers) and generic kernel that loads much things i don't need.
With custom kernel and new, proper, motherboard my Arch will respond before i think what command to give ;)